# How to start Pipeline B automatically when Pipeline A finishes successfully

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

My build pipeline triggers upon commits into “main” branch of my Azure Repo, builds my React app, executes custom PS script that copies selected css and js files from build folder to an external system (Dev) – this serves well for Dev.

But I need idea for ***triggers for Test and Prod pipelines*** upon successful execution of the build pipeline.

Since I have a single Repo, I can’t use “main” as triggers for them.

Answer (score 3):

You do this by adding a [pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource) to your release pipeline, defining a [pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) to make the build pipeline's completion automatically queue up the release pipeline.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: build-pipeline
    source: build-pipeline
    trigger: true
      branches:
        include:
          - main
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vince - my only question is, is there a way to trigger Pipeline B only if Pipeline A executed successfully?

Comment: That's what it does! It's right there in the docs I linked: "*add a pipeline trigger to run your pipeline upon the **successful completion** of the triggering pipeline.*"

Comment: Is there a way PipelineA can pass parameter values for PipelineB ?

Comment: Not through this method, no. Pipeline B will run with each parameter's default value.

Comment: Okay, any other method you may reckon?